# How to delete Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

I want to delete Google Play Services in the Google Play Developer Console, but I can't. Here is what I did:

1. I published my game to Google Play without Google Play Services.

[image]

2. I decided that I want Google Play Services in my game, so I integrated them in the source code.
3. After that I created Google Play Services for my game in the Google Play Developer Console.

[image]

4. But the created Google Play Services didn't work. The were Unpublished at that moment. I read that in order for them to work, you have to publish them. I published them, they still don't work and I can't delete them. In order to delete them I must unlink the game, but since the game is published I can't unlink it. I asked Google Support what to do, they told me to delete the project in the Google API Console and after 7 days the game will be unlinked. There has been 15 days since then and nothing happens. Please tell me what can I do.

Comment: On Stackoverflow: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094031/remove-linked-application-from-google-game-services-in-developer-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094031/remove-linked-application-from-google-game-services-in-developer-console). If you look at the first answer, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

*Here are the instructions on how to delete a project:*

1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Click Game Services.
3. Select the project.
4. At the bottom of the Game Details page, click the link to go to the **API Console Project.**
5. In the API Console Project, on the left menu, click **APIs & Auth > Credentials**.
6. Under **"Client ID for Android application"**, click Delete.
7. On the left menu, click Projects.
8. Click Billing & settings.
9. Click Delete project.

To confirm that your project has been deleted, go back to your Google Play Developer Console and click Games services Game Services.

I found that from [this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/6097563?hl=en&ref_topic=15868#ts=6097687,6097659).